# background-size:contain cuts off image edges in Firefox

Tags: html, css

Let's say that this is my HTML.

```
<div id="spirit_tutorial_reward">
   <div id="spirit_tutorial_reward_icon" style="background:url({$MEDIA_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_PATH}appimages/gift_icon_spirit.png) no-repeat;background-size: contain;"></div>
   <div id="spirit_tutorial_reward_header">45 Spirit</div>
   <div id="spirit_tutorial_reward_text">Use Spirit to recruit new Rusherz in the Locker Room!</div>
</div>
```

And this is my styling:

```
#spirit_tutorial_reward
{
    position:absolute;
    top:77px;
    left:371px;
    width:45%;  
}
#spirit_tutorial_reward_icon
{
    background:url(../images/gift_icon_spirit.png) top no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    float:left; 
}
#spirit_tutorial_reward_header
{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:"NFLEndzoneSansBold";
    color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:69px;
    top:0px;
    float:left; 
}

#spirit_tutorial_reward_text
{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:"NFLEndzoneSansBold";
    color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:69px;
    top:22px;
    float:left; 
}
```

On no-zoom or normal mode , the images appear to have chopped off on Firefox (see attached image) but when I zoom my page , the image appears to becoming better (see attached image). I am facing this issue only in Firefox. Can anyone here help me out. [image: without zoom] [image: with zoom]

EDIT : [**FIDDLE demo for the problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbruG/)

Comment: Looks like you want `background-size:cover`, not `contain` ...

Comment: @CBroe : That's not making any difference. The images are still getting chopped.

Comment: @CBroe : added an example on JSFiddle. Take a look on Chrome and Firefox . And oh , I am no Firefox 22.0 on Windows 7 , if that helps in solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a [subpixel problem](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/). That's the reason the image works fine in some zoom modes.

I edited your jsFiddle to set the `background-size` to 99.9%, and then works properly. You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bbruG/1/).

Note: I put the `!important` to overwrite the inline styles... feeling lazy, you know ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the subpixel problem. Accepting this as the answer because it's more easier to use a `%` value for the size instead of actual pixels.
Talking about laziness : It's the mother of all bad habits , but ultimately it's our mother and we should respect her ;)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in one of my recent encounters. This prevented the image from being cut off:

```
transform: rotate(0.0001deg);
```

Comment: After struggling with a stupid bug where the background of an element was cut, I found your solution and it worked in my case, for IE9 (`-ms-transform`), IE10 and IE11! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting background-size to 59px which i did in that fiddle and worked as expected.
i.e

```
 <div id="spirit_tutorial_reward_icon" style="background:url({$MEDIA_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_PATH}appimages/gift_icon_spirit.png) no-repeat;background-size:59px;"></div>
```

If this answer was helpful.Dont forget to mark to apport or mark as answer

Thanks 
AB

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. But do you know why does the image break when I give a `background-size : contain`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to cover whole page.. apply the image to background and give background size:cover to it..
you may try this:

```
body {
background-image: url(your-image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #EEE;
background-size: cover;
}
```

you may refer this http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: Thanks for your time, but that is not what I want.My images are getting chopped on Firefox when I give a `background-size` to it.